# Material Design Lite not working with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, material-design-lite

I have a simple page that has a header and drawer navigation, as below

**My problem is**, whenever I navigate to another page, the drawer menu icon (hamburger icon) disappears. I was able to trigger the icon to show up using `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` at Chrome's console.

I tried to remove `//= require turbolinks` and everything continues to work, of course at the cost of my pages loading speed.

FYI, I moved javascripts to the bottom of `<body>` to improve first page loading speed. I also tried to move the javascripts back to `<head>` tag, with and without `data-turbolinks-track`, the problem still recur.

I do hope MDL and Turbolinks can work together without costing me (first page) loading speed.

Any help much appreciated.

```
<body>
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title"><%= yield(:title) %></span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <!-- some links -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title"><%= yield(:title) %></span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <!-- some links -->
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <%= yield %>
  </main>
</div>


<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => 'false' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false %>
</body>
```

Update: the only way I able to make both work together is to add `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` at the very end of `<body>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another solution is using the TurboLinks' **page:change** event to call **upgradeDom**.

```js
document.addEventListener('page:change', function() {
  componentHandler.upgradeDom();
});
```

Comment: With TurboLinks 5, the event is 'turbolinks:load' instead of 'page:change'.

Comment: so this fixed my issue when I go forward to other pages. But it doesnt fix the issue for the MDL drop downs or the drawer. Have you seen this issue?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! @JohnPollard This fixed my issue with mdl drop downs (usings Rails 5 and TurboLinks 5, thus the event I used is 'turbolinks:load').